# TRAC SvnAuthzAdminPlugin install error

Tags: svn, plugins, installation, trac

Have a problems installing the plugin **SvnAuthzAdminPlugin**.

I run:

```
easy_install trac-hacks.org/svn/svnauthzadminplugin/0.12
```

Plugin directory is created here:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SvnAuthzAdminPlugin-0.2-py2.7.egg
```

Resynchronization run, but I do not see **SvnAuthzAdminPlugin** of plugins list.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Not enough information to give an answer. Just a guess: Do you use Apache and forgot to restart it?

Comment: yep, I use Apache. I rebooted the apache. still do not see the plugin in the list

Comment: In this case it means there was a plugin load error you may see in your log/trag.log file. Or you haven't enabled the plugin on your Admin web page.

Comment: What do you have set for the `plugins_dir` variable in your trac.ini file?